# Changing the column name of dataframe after indexing in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I used this code to fill my dataset with NaN values randomly:

```
np.random.seed(1234)

total_cells = df.shape[0] * df.shape[1]
df = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = "index")
df.loc[np.random.randint(0, total_cells, int(total_cells * .25)), "value"] = np.NaN
df.pivot(index = "index", columns = "variable")
```

After pivot my columns look like when I check

```
df.columns.to_list()
[('value', 'AGE'), ('value','DATE'),.........,('value','TIME')]
```

but I want them to just be ['AGE', 'DATE',...,'TIME'].

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `values` to `pivot` is simplier way:

```
df.pivot(index = "index", columns = "variable", value='value')
```

Or:

```
df.pivot(index = "index", columns = "variable").droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
```

Comment: Hi jezrael. The second solution worked with droplevel part. Thanks!

Comment: @Jezrael, how is this suppose to work i.e. passing same parameter twice. It gives `keyword argument repeated` error when I tried this

Comment: @MuhammadHassan - good point, answer was edited.

Comment: @OjjasviPuri - now working both solution correctly.

Comment: @jezrael is there a way to fix that the same fields get the value NaN whenever we use this code? Like setting a random_state= '1234'?

Comment: @jezrael so you mean it should be like this: df = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = "index"), np.random.seed(1234) and then this line
df.loc[np.random.randint(0, total_cells, int(total_cells * .25)), "value"] = np.NaN

Comment: @OjjasviPuri - added to question.